# Unity - iOS/Android build size too high/large for no apparent reason

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, build, size

I have a very small game with just 2 scenes and least number of assets.3 plugins have been used like Unity IAP, Googleplaygames plugin and google admob plugin. Thats all there is. Yet the build size is way too high. Over 600MB(over 700MB in archive)!!

Below I have posted the build report in the editor log for both iOS and android. As you can see no specific category is taking up much space but yet the complete size is large for both andorid and ios. iOS size way more than android as well.

Does anyone know whats causing this extra size as its not even showing in any other category?

iOS -

```
Build Report
Uncompressed usage by category:
Textures      17.0 mb    2.7% 
Meshes        0.0 kb     0.0% 
Animations    4.9 kb     0.0% 
Sounds        547.9 kb   0.1% 
Shaders       15.6 kb    0.0% 
Other Assets  237.0 kb   0.0% 
Levels        63.2 kb    0.0% 
Scripts       399.6 kb   0.1% 
Included DLLs 0.0 kb     0.0% 
File headers  28.0 kb    0.0% 
Complete size 632.2 mb   100.0%
```

Android -

```
Build Report
Uncompressed usage by category:
Textures      16.3 mb    12.0% 
Meshes        0.0 kb     0.0% 
Animations    4.9 kb     0.0% 
Sounds        548.0 kb   0.4% 
Shaders       11.8 kb    0.0% 
Other Assets  237.0 kb   0.2% 
Levels        63.3 kb    0.0% 
Scripts       1.5 mb     1.1% 
Included DLLs 5.1 mb     3.8% 
File headers  204.5 kb   0.1% 
Complete size 136.1 mb   100.0%
```

Unity Version - Unity 2018.1.0f2 Personal(64bit)

I tried "fast but no exception" script call optimization in ios but no difference. This game should hardly take 70-100MB. Few MB difference i can understand but this is way too high!
I wont be able to release the app with this much size. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After completing the build for release I realised that the above values do not determine the final size.
As you can see -

https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1431764625

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ResurgeLabs.ChasingStars

My final game both on android and ios were less than 100 mb. So all satisfactory and as expected. Hence this question is not valid.