# Unity iOS Build Size Enormous but Textures Small

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I'm building a **unity** **gam**e for the first time.  When I *build* for **iOS** I get a full *build size* greater than *700mb* but in my build report it says that the user `assets` are only 71mb.  So what is the rest of this coming from?

I know this is a bit vague but I'm really stumped.  Not so much looking for an answer as for where I should direct my research.  Other relevant info:

- My game is **2D**
- It is comprised of *8 levels* that each has a simple **drag-and-drop puzzle** (it's for kids).
- No complex `animations` or `scripts`
- No packages installed

Build report below:

```
Build Report
Uncompressed usage by category (Percentages based on user generated assets only):
Textures               44.7 mb   62.9% 
Meshes                 0.0 kb    0.0% 
Animations             183.1 kb  0.3% 
Sounds                 10.7 mb   15.0% 
Shaders                183.8 kb  0.3% 
Other Assets           289.2 kb  0.4% 
Levels                 10.7 mb   15.1% 
Scripts                524.2 kb  0.7% 
Included DLLs          3.8 mb    5.3% 
File headers           53.0 kb   0.1% 
Total User Assets      71.1 mb   100.0% 
Complete build size    723.2 mb
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Similiar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658456/unity-ios-build-size-is-way-big and https://answers.unity.com/questions/1149641/very-large-ios-build-size-unity-5.html

Comment: Official documentation for optimizing the size: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html

Comment: Unity includes a bunch of analytics 'packages' by default. Start by getting rid of them. They're in Menu Window -> Package Manager. But this will only strip about 200MB, I think. Something else is definitely going wrong.

Comment: @Confused yes your are confused and you are also confusing me

Answer (score 0):

[There was reports](https://forum.unity.com/threads/strange-build-size-report-in-editor-log-how-to-interpret.533941/) that Unity do not include size of mp4 files in build report. Check your special folders like StreamingAssets folder for such files included into build.

Also check if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53005688/unity-ios-android-build-size-too-high-large-for-no-apparent-reason) suits you.

Would be great if you attach information about what version of Unity you are using.

Comment: Using Unity 2019.4.1

Comment: Probably 2019.1.4f

Answer (score 0):

Besides your assets, I am suspecting whether "Strip Engine Code" is enabled in player settings or not?

It's enabled by default. But worth checking. Quoting from Unity Scripting API:

"If this is enabled, unused modules and classes of the Unity Engine codebase will be removed in IL2CPP builds. This will result in a smaller binary size. It is recommended to use this setting, however, you may want to disable it if you suspect this causes issues with your project. Note that byte code stripping of managed assemblies is always enabled for the IL2CPP scripting backend."

Reference:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings-stripEngineCode.html

Comment: I have it enabled and it didn't reduce the size at all.  That was my most frustrating moment actually. I made sure that box was checked and did a build and no difference in size.